# Missing Refresh Token Gmail API

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail API for a web app I built, but I am missing the Refresh Token from Credentials. The code is identical in my local machine and production, and in testing everything works as expected, but in production I don't get a Refresh Token.
The app is set to Production and has been verified by Google.

Here's the code I use:

## Create authorisation url

```
`state = secrets.token_urlsafe(16)
session['state'] = state

flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES, state=state)
flow.redirect_uri = url_for('callback', _external=True)
authorization_url, _ = flow.authorization_url(access_type='offline', include_granted_scopes='true')`
```

## Generate credentials

```
`state = session['state']
flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES, state=state)
flow.redirect_uri = url_for('callback', _external=True)
authorization_response = request.url
flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response, access_type="offline", prompt="consent")

credentials = flow.credentials
if credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
    credentials.refresh(Request())
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)`
```

Any ideas why this difference is behaviour between testing and production?

Comment: Maybe that means after token expiration you must re-login?

Comment: For certain web-based scripting languages, Google may not issue a new refresh token all the time. Google thinks that the user will have saved their refresh token for future use. 

For any events that you need to obtain a new refresh token, you can revoke the user's access token. However, this action will cause the user to revoke your access to their data. Once the user logs in again, they will be prompted to grant you access and you can receive a new refresh token.

Comment: I think I found what happened. The credentials I created for testing are about 2 months older than the ones in production. I believe that the refresh token is being provided about 5-6 months after the credentials are created, and the app verified. This is the only explanation I could find that would make sense